# How to publish dart library that has flutter tests?

Tags: dart-pub

My dart library has flutter tests. I run the tests with `flutter test test\flutter` and it works perfectly.

However, when I try to publish it with either `dart pub publish` or `flutter pub publish`, I get error:

```
This package does not have flutter in the `dependencies` or `dev_dependencies` section of `pubspec.yaml`.
    ╷
  7 │ import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  clock: ^1.1.1
  collection: ^1.15.0
  vm_service: ^9.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  meta: ^1.8.0
  test: ^1.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding flutter to dev dependencies made it working:

```
dev_dependencies:
  ...
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```